# How to Open a Hyperlink (2) in the same window which was opened with a click to Hyperlink1

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I am working on a requirement with a (Parent) web page having some links suppose Link1,Link2 and Link3.when i click Link1 which will be opened in a new window which is active window1 (child) and when i click Link2/Link3 the page should open in the same window (window1) .

Question:
Is there a way in Javascript/Jquery/Ajax to implement this functionality.Please do share your valuable thoughts on this.

Note:
If none of the links are opened then a new window should pop up. I know that we have Option target="_blank/_self/_top" etc in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You want to create your own named window.
Just add `target="SomeName"` to all of the links, and they will reuse the named window if it still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked the JS/ jQuery way,

JavaScript way is,

```
window.open('http://www.example.org','window1');
```

Comment: can you please share small snippet or working example that helps me, as i am looking to use the opened window1 and when next set of links are to be opened i need to use same Window1 .

Comment: @user1227648 Show your JS codes, Can't help than this without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function open_win(url) 
{
window.open(url,"hello","",true);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="open_win('http://www.google.com')"> Google </a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="open_win('http://www.yahoo.com')"> Yahoo </a><br>
<a href="#" onclick="open_win('http://www.gmail.com')"> Gmail </a>
</body>
</html>
Issue is resolved thanks,i Thought too much / some thing else which lead this        misconception. Thanks
```